# How to split strings of an element in list and write it to a new csv file?

Tags: python, list, file, csv

I have a list which looks like below:

```
['PSHELL       102  156800    1.55  156800      1.  156800\n',
 'PSHELL       103  143120    1.55  143120      1.  143120\n',
 'PSHELL       104  143120    1.55  143120      1.  143120\n',
 'PSHELL       105  114700     0.7  114700      1.  114700\n',
 'PSHELL       106  114700     0.7  114700      1.  114700\n',
 'PSHELL       107  114700     1.3  114700      1.  114700\n']
```

I want to remove the last three strings in every element of list. And populate it with different values.

e.g: remove 156800 1. 156800\n and the same way for every element. And add new values there.

I am expecting the below result:

```
['PSHELL       102  156800    1.55  1.085 2.015
 'PSHELL       103....]

Here 1.085= 1.55-(1.55 x 0.3)
     2.015= 1.55+(1.55 x 0.3)

I tried achieving this by converting my list to dataframe, but it is not allowing me to do above math calculation.
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you tried to attempt in order to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
data = ['PSHELL       102  156800    1.55  156800      1.  156800\n',
 'PSHELL       103  143120    1.55  143120      1.  143120\n',
 'PSHELL       104  143120    1.55  143120      1.  143120\n',
 'PSHELL       105  114700     0.7  114700      1.  114700\n',
 'PSHELL       106  114700     0.7  114700      1.  114700\n',
 'PSHELL       107  114700     1.3  114700      1.  114700\n']

result = []
for i in data:
    val = i.strip().split()[:-3]        #Remove last 3 elements using list slicing. 
    lVal = float(val[-1])
    val += [str(lVal - (lVal * 0.3)), str(lVal + (lVal * 0.3))]  #Add new values
    result.append("       ".join(val))   #Form String.
```

**Output:**

```
['PSHELL       102       156800       1.55       1.085       2.015',
 'PSHELL       103       143120       1.55       1.085       2.015',
 'PSHELL       104       143120       1.55       1.085       2.015',
 'PSHELL       105       114700       0.7       0.49       0.91',
 'PSHELL       106       114700       0.7       0.49       0.91',
 'PSHELL       107       114700       1.3       0.91       1.69']
```